# NextJs 13 API to handle uploaded files does not work using formidable

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, ckeditor5, formidable

I have a NextJs 13 project that requires and API which can handle a file that is sent to it. I have used formidable for handling the middleware

My app/api/uploadfile/route.ts file (code has been minimized for concentration)

```
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
};

const asyncParse = (req:any) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });

export async function PUT(req:any, res:any) {
  console.log("Receiving");
  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    const result = await asyncParse(req);
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  }
}
```

Here i call the api using the endpoint localhost:3000/api/uploadfile via postman
[image: Postman SS for reference]

I get an **error**

```
error - TypeError: req.on is not a function
    at IncomingForm.parse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:90:9)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/uploadfile/route.ts:18:14)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at asyncParse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/uploadfile/route.ts:14:27)
    at PUT (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/uploadfile/route.ts:29:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:219:24)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:92:36)
    at NoopContextManager.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:360:30)
    at ContextAPI.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:30:58)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:953:34)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:993:36)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:81:107)
    at NoopContextManager.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:360:30)
    at ContextAPI.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:30:58)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:81:32)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:214:49)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:345:14)
    at Object.wrap (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/async-storage/static-generation-async-storage-wrapper.js:32:24)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:171:93)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:345:14)
    at Object.wrap (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/async-storage/request-async-storage-wrapper.js:59:24)
    at AppRouteRouteModule.execute (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:170:87)
    at AppRouteRouteModule.handle (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:259:41)
    at RouteHandlerManager.handle (E:\Projects\Templates\backend-template\node_modules\next\dist\server\future\route-handler-managers\route-handler-manager.js:22:29)
    at doRender (E:\Projects\Templates\backend-template\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:848:58)
    at cacheEntry1.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (E:\Projects\Templates\backend-template\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1059:34)
    at E:\Projects\Templates\backend-template\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:83:42
    at ResponseCache.get (E:\Projects\Templates\backend-template\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:131:11)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (E:\Projects\Templates\backend-template\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:978:54)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

**Things i have tried**

1. Using multer as an alternative(weird artefacts with NextJS 13 and typescript)(have tried various implementations)
2. Using POST and GET in place of PUT in the code example
3. Googling the error and also using chatgpt
4. Changing versions of formidable to v2/v3 and also to v1.2.2 the outcome is the same
5. Better code to upload to my prisma db(but it fails in the calling the api step itself)

**My end goal**

I want to use this API endpoint in my ckeditor5 implementation(as the image upload adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need formidable anymore for it. Next.js 13 added a new feature  `formData();` to their application that handles file upload and they restricted the use of formidable which handles this functionality. So this is it (I'm answering your goal: **using CKEditor5** to handle this. Might work using postman as well):

```
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const file: any = formData.get("upload");
```

for me I needed the file to be uploaded on cloudinary so this is how I solved it.

```
 const formData = await request.formData();
    const file: any = formData.get("upload");
    
    const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    let uploadedImageUrl: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cloudinary.uploader
        .upload_stream({}, function (error, result: any) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
            return;
          }

          resolve(result);
        })
        .end(buffer);
    });
```

If you `console.log(result)` you will see the returned value of your file. return the secure_url and it will return the image into the editor.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like we don't need formidable, multer, or multiparty with Nextjs since it handles this. If you come across a similar issue, try this. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48875#issuecomment-1592301037

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving the api to the pages folder(pages/api/uploadfile.ts) without any code changes.

I found this as the only way to make it work. What i guess happens is that the api from the app directory is not accessible to external apps like postman, but I'm not entirely sure.